# How to find artifacts from Artifactory that have a specific property value using REST API

Tags: rest, jenkins-pipeline, artifactory, artifactory-query-lang

I want to search for all the artifacts in Artifactory that have some property field:

```
items.find({"@some_property" : {"$eq" : "some_value"}})
```

How can I do it using a REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

Following AQL query

```
items.find(
 {
 "repo":{"$eq":"mymavenrepo"},
 "name": {"$match" : "*.jar"}
 }
)
```

can be translated to this REST call

```
http://localhost/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=*jar&re
pos=jcenter-cache
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the when I run it from bush, it get the ```&``` wrong, so it run the cmd  until the ```&``` in the background  and failed to find the rest, instead of running it as one cmd

Comment: To use in bash, use double quotes around the URL 
`curl "http://localhost/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=*jar&re
pos=jcenter-cache"`

Answer (score 0):

Easier with [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles):

```
jfrog rt s '*' --props some_property=some_value
```

Example results:

```
[Info] Searching artifacts...
[Info] Found 1 artifact.
[
  {
    "path": "generic-local/hello",
    "type": "file",
    "size": 6,
    "created": "2020-11-29T14:00:18.410Z",
    "modified": "2020-11-29T14:00:18.222Z",
    "sha1": "f572d396fae9206628714fb2ce00f72e94f2258f",
    "md5": "b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184",
    "props": {
      "some_property": [
        "some_value"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [AQL](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-ArtifactoryQueryLanguage(AQL)) REST API method, for example:

```
curl -uuser:password -H "content-type: text/plain" -XPOST http://localhost:8081/artifactory/api/search/aql -d "items.find({\"@foo\" : {\"\$eq\" : \"bar\"}})"
```