# How to modify the artifactCleanup plugin to keep just the last 10 artifacts in repo?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, artifactory

I found the artifactCleanup plugin (https://github.com/jfrog/artifactory-user-plugins/blob/master/cleanup/artifactCleanup/artifactCleanup.groovy)

I managed to implement it into my jenkins server, but now I need to update it a little.
Instead of cleaning everything up that was not downloaded in the past X months, I want to keep just the last 10 artifacts in the repo (in each subfolder as well)

For example:

```
Main_Repo
   -folder1 (has 15 artifacts)
   -folder2 (has 20 artifacts)
   -art1
   -art2
   -...
   -art25
```

I need to keep the following:

```
Main_Repo
   -folder1 (has 10 artifacts)
   -folder2 (has 10 artifacts)
   -art1
   -art2
   -...
   -art10
```

Would that be possible?

The main function is this:

```
private def artifactCleanup(String timeUnit, int timeInterval, String[] repos, log, paceTimeMS, dryRun = false, disablePropertiesSupport = false) {
    log.info "Starting artifact cleanup for repositories $repos, until $timeInterval ${timeUnit}s ago with pacing interval $paceTimeMS ms, dryrun: $dryRun, disablePropertiesSupport: $disablePropertiesSupport"

    cancelOnNullRepos(repos,'repos parameter must be specified before initiating cleanup.')

    // Create Map(repo, paths) of skiped paths (or others properties supported in future ...)
    def skip = [:]
    if ( ! disablePropertiesSupport && repos){
        skip = getSkippedPaths(repos)
    }

    def calendarUntil = Calendar.getInstance()

    calendarUntil.add(mapTimeUnitToCalendar(timeUnit), -timeInterval)

    def calendarUntilFormatted = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm").format(calendarUntil.getTime());
    log.info "Removing all artifacts not downloaded since $calendarUntilFormatted"

    Global.stopCleaning = false
    int cntFoundArtifacts = 0
    int cntNoDeletePermissions = 0
    long bytesFound = 0
    long bytesFoundWithNoDeletePermission = 0
    def artifactsCleanedUp = searches.artifactsNotDownloadedSince(calendarUntil, calendarUntil, repos)
    artifactsCleanedUp.find {
        try {
            while ( Global.pauseCleaning ) {
                log.info "Pausing by request"
                sleep( 60000 )
            }

            if ( Global.stopCleaning ) {
                log.info "Stopping by request, ending loop"
                return true
            }

            if ( ! disablePropertiesSupport && skip[ it.repoKey ] && StringUtils.startsWithAny(it.path, skip[ it.repoKey ])){
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()){
                    log.debug "Skip $it"
                }
                return false
            }

            bytesFound += repositories.getItemInfo(it)?.getSize()
            cntFoundArtifacts++
            if (!security.canDelete(it)) {
                bytesFoundWithNoDeletePermission += repositories.getItemInfo(it)?.getSize()
                cntNoDeletePermissions++
            }
            if (dryRun) {
                log.info "Found $it "
                log.info "\t==> currentUser: ${security.currentUser().getUsername()}"
                log.info "\t==> canDelete: ${security.canDelete(it)}"

            } else {
                if (security.canDelete(it)) {
                    log.info "Deleting $it"
                    repositories.delete it
                    log.info "Deleted..."
                } else {
                    log.info "Can't delete $it (user ${security.currentUser().getUsername()} has no delete permissions), "
                }
            }
        } catch (ItemNotFoundRuntimeException ex) {
            log.info "Failed to find $it, skipping"
        }

        def sleepTime = (Global.paceTimeMS > 0) ? Global.paceTimeMS : paceTimeMS
        if (sleepTime > 0) {
            sleep( sleepTime )
        }

        return false
    }

    if (dryRun) {
        log.info "Dry run - nothing deleted. Found $cntFoundArtifacts artifacts consuming $bytesFound bytes"
        if (cntNoDeletePermissions > 0) {
            log.info "$cntNoDeletePermissions artifacts cannot be deleted due to lack of permissions ($bytesFoundWithNoDeletePermission bytes)"
        }
    } else {
        log.info "Finished cleanup, deleting $cntFoundArtifacts artifacts that took up $bytesFound bytes"
        if (cntNoDeletePermissions > 0) {
            log.info "$cntNoDeletePermissions artifacts could not be deleted due to lack of permissions ($bytesFoundWithNoDeletePermission bytes)"
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not sure where can I find for example the "search" object, or the function it calls in the following line:

```
def artifactsCleanedUp = searches.artifactsNotDownloadedSince(calendarUntil, calendarUntil, repos)
```

Hope you can help me.
Thank you for your time

Comment: So, I need this feature for jfrog.

Comment: yes, turns out I have no available debugging mechanism for this one, so I am working now on a jenkins pipeline to do it manually, without the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Preferably, your build artifacts are marked in a unique way, for instance using Artifactory properties. And then you can access artifacts with a given property. [finding artifacts based on property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65058402/how-to-find-artifacts-from-artifactory-that-have-a-specific-property-value-using) This way, it is ensured that you are save to access the right artifact without risk of mixing them up.

If the above mentioned is not possible, I would try to solve this by using timestamps and an AQL statement.
You would need to get the timestamp of the 10. build and you could consider to compare it to timestamps on Artifactory. I doubt this is fail safe since you can mess up time stamps.
See: [Date and Time Format in AQL](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/date-and-time-format-in-aql)